# Looping regression commands

Tags: r

I'm going to simplify my problem as much as to prove that I'm not just throwing my assignment at you guys. I really want to learn how to get loop to work with regressions.

Let's suppose I want to run two OLS but I don't want to type the same ols command twice OR add another series of commands into my script. This is because a) I actually have way more than two regressions and b) I want to try to code this as efficient as I can (I have tried copying and pasting same ols commands). Also, I'm not just running a simple OLS as I'm also running HAC estimator depending on the serial correlation and heteroskedasticity test.

The code that i have came up with so far is,

Packages

```
if (!require("lmtest")) install.packages("lmtest") 
library("lmtest")
if (!require("sandwich")) install.packages("sandwich") 
library("sandwich")
```

Data

```
data<-read.csv(file.choose())
x1<-data$x1
x2<-data$x2
x3<-data$x4
x5<-data$x5
x6<-data$x6
x7<-data$x7
y1<-data$y1
```

Regressions

```
reg1<-(y1 ~ x1 + x2 + x3 + x4)
reg2<-(y1 ~ x2 + x4 + x6 + x7)

p<-0.05
```

Loop

```
for (i in 1:2) {

#OLS#
ols[i]<-lm(reg[i])

#Breusch-Pagan Test#
bptest(ols[i],varformula = NULL, studentize = TRUE)
bpp<-bptest(ols[i])$p.value
if(bpp>p) hs<-F else hs<-T

#Breusch-Godfrey Serial Correlation Test#
bgtest(ols[i],order=2,order.by=NULL,type=c("Chisq"))
bgp<-bgtest(ols[i])$p.value
if(bgp>p) sc<-F else sc<-T

#HAC Estimator#
HAC<-vcovHAC(ols[i],order.by=NULL,prewhite=FALSE,adjust=TRUE,diagnostics=FALSE,sandwich = TRUE,ar.method = "ols")
if (sc==T|hs==T) coeftest(ols[i],vcov.=HAC) else ols[i]
if (sc==T|hs==T) write.csv(coeftest(ols[i],vcov.=HAC),file="ols[i]HAC.csv") else write.csv(summary(ols[i])$coefficient,file="ols1.csv")
}
```

When I run this I get

```
Error in stats::model.frame(formula = reg[i], drop.unused.levels = TRUE) : object 'reg' not found
```

I have also tried the above code with

```
for (i in reg[1]:reg[2]) {
}
```

but it only returned

```
Error: object 'reg' not found.
```

Where did I go wrong?

Comment: You should declare

reg[1]<-(y1 ~ x1 + x2 + x3 + x4)
reg[2]<-(y1 ~ x2 + x4 + x6 + x7)

Comment: As the error says there is no `reg` there is `reg1` and `reg2` neither of which are referenced by `reg[1]` or `reg[2]`

Comment: Try creating a new object. `reg <- list(reg1 = x ~ y1 + y2, reg2 = x ~ x1 + y3)` and then call it using `reg[[i]]`.

Comment: Btw., `lm` got a `data` parameter. No need to copy the columns out of the data.frame.

Comment: Thanks for commenting but none of your instructions seem to work.

Comment: Just to clarify, the difference between your regressions is the formula used, right? Is there any other difference?

Comment: What is the error this time?

Comment: @coffeinjunky Yes the only difference is the variables within the formula. 

adiana, I don't think reg[1] works because [] is a search function in r. So if I type reg[1] outright then I think R recognizes that as  a variable.
    Warning message:
In reg[1] <- (y1 ~ regression equation) :
  number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is too long for a comment, so I post it as a partial answer.

The difference seems to be the formula, and you are asking for a way to make your code more efficient. One way is to use a `list` of formulae and then combine the list with `lapply`. For instance,

```
reg <- list(
  reg1 = as.formula(y1 ~ x1 + x2 + x3 + x4),
  reg2 = as.formula(y1 ~ x2 + x4 + x6 + x7)
  )

ols <- lapply(reg, function(x) lm(x, data=data))
```

Here, `ols` is a list of two elements, each of which is a regression corresponding to the formula-list. You can use the same principle for other functions, for instance:

```
bgtests <- lapply(ols, function(x) 
                  bgtest(x,order=2,order.by=NULL,type=c("Chisq")))
```

This executes your `bgtest` function for each regression stored in `ols`. In a similar fashion, you can write it up so that it executes your heteroskedasticity corrections etc. The important point is this: you supply a `list` to `lapply`, and each element of that list is what is passed onto the function that you provide. The output of `lapply` is then a `list` with the output of that function.

In case you don't want to use `lapply` and to adress your actual question: the problem in your code is that there is no object called `reg`. Subsetting a non-existing object such as `reg[1]` hence does not work. If you execute the first lines of my code above, `reg[1]` and `reg[2]` become defined so that your loop should work.

Comment: Are you telling me to remove the loop function?

Comment: Are you implying that looping will be inefficient for this exercise? And if it is, why and how so?

Comment: If `for` loops or `lapply` is more efficient in terms of execution is somewhat off topic here, I think. You can google this topic and you will find many good comparisons. In terms of how to organize code and code output, as well as how to write code efficiently, I would always prefer the above approach.

Comment: I don't understand the last comment. I've tried replacing all the formulae with reg but it didn't work. I really appreciate your help, btw.

Comment: I am totally lost at this point because the code that I posted above is a simplified version of what I'm really doing and doesn't actually contain any data. Exactly what am I supposed to type? Also this is my second week with R and i've had 0 programming experience prior to that.

Comment: Type `str(reg)` and post the output here.

Comment: So, are you saying that you get the very same error message that you posted in your opening question?

Comment: No, but I wasn't able to implement your code because I honestly don't know how to. Is there a way for me to send you the codes so that you can have a look?

Comment: @coffieinjunky I am now getting this error. Error in formula.default(object, env = baseenv()) : invalid formula

Comment: It seems that the error in your initial question has been pointed out and resolved. You did not have an object called `reg`, so that subsetting `reg` with `reg[1]` and `reg[2]` did not work. It is customary here on Stackoverflow to accept answers to the initial question, and it is not customary here to keep saying that the solution does not work if, in fact, it worked but some other unrelated bug caused a problem further down the line. If you face other issues, feel free to post in a new thread.

Comment: As has already been pointed out in the inital comments, you need to change `reg[i]` to `reg[[i]]`.

Comment: Ok so I made the list containing all my regressions and used lm(reg[[i]]). But now I seem to be getting this error. Error in ols[i] <- lm(reg[[i]]) : object 'ols' not found

Comment: Am i supposed to change ols[i] to ols[[i]] as well?

Edit: I've done ols[[i]] and it returns the same error. Error in ols[[i]] <- lm(reg[[i]]) : object 'ols' not found.

Comment: This seems to be the same problem as before. You try to subset a non-existing object. You could either define the object, e.g. with `ols <- list()` put before your loop, or you could remove the line in your loop and copy-paste my code in which I define `ols`, again put before your loop. In general, if an error message says "object not found", it typically means that there is no such object and you need to fix that.

Comment: @coffieinjunky Hey, I've succeeded in creating a loop by assigning reg1 and reg2, followed by putting those into a list. I then created ols list by assigning each ols. Thank you for your help. Unfortunately, I do have one more problem and that is I can no longer store my regression results automatically. R seems to only save the results for the last regression ran in the loop. Could you give me some advice with this? The command that I'm using is, if (sc==T|hs==T) write.csv(coeftest(ols[[i]],vcov.=HAC),file="ols[[i]]HAC.csv") else write.csv(summary(ols[[i]])$coefficient,file="ols[[i]].csv").

Comment: Great, I am glad to hear your problem has been resolved. Please consider accepting the answer that you think helped you the most, so that other people can see that the issue has been resolved. You do this by clicking on the `v` sign next to the beginning of the answer. Regarding your issue: the commands are fine but you use the very same filename for each regression, namely `ols[[i]]HAC.csv` or `ols[[i]].csv`. You need to assign different file names. `?paste0` can help you with that.

Comment: Does that mean I'm going to need to create a list containing all possible file names (mainly for HAC and normal) then use them in the command?

Comment: You need to create different filenames, either outside or inside the loop. Look at what happens when you execute `for(i in 1:5) print("ols[[i]].csv")` as well as `for(i in 1:5) print(i)`. Just `paste` your filename together in the loop. Try to execute `for(i in 1:5) print(paste0("This is ", i))`.

Answer (score 1):

The 'get' function is what you want, in conjunction with 'paste'. Below I fit two regressions using the cars data in R. Then I want to write a loop that extracts its coefficients. The 'get' function goes and find the object that matches the object name you specified.

```
> (reg1 <- lm(dist ~ speed, data = cars))

Call:
lm(formula = dist ~ speed, data = cars)

Coefficients:
(Intercept)        speed  
    -17.579        3.932  

> (reg2 <- lm(dist ~ 1 + I(speed^2), data = cars))

Call:
lm(formula = dist ~ 1 + I(speed^2), data = cars)

Coefficients:
(Intercept)   I(speed^2)  
      8.860        0.129  

> coeff <- matrix(0, nrow = 2, ncol = 2)
> for (i in 1:2)
+ {
+
+ # Main step
+ model <- get(paste("reg", i, sep = ""))
+ coeff[i,] <- coefficients(model)
+ }
> coeff
           [,1]      [,2]
[1,] -17.579095 3.9324088
[2,]   8.860049 0.1289687
>
```

Comment: I guess this could work but because I'm not just running OLS but HAC depending on autocorrelation & heteroskedasticity tests, I'm going to need another lines that specify which coefficients to send out to your loop command.

Is there a more efficient way to loop?

Comment: There is almost always a better alternative than using `get` here.

Comment: I think the other answer is the more efficient way.